# Creating maven project from local Maven repo

Tags: maven, project

I am trying to create a maven project in a Windows virtual machine. But am unable to create as there is a proxy setting that doesn't allow me to connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

But I do have another link that have the maven repos. But am not sure how to create the maven project using the link that I have. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify another repository in your `pom.xml` file, but you’ll have to do it for every maven project you’ll build.

You can also specify that repository in your `settings.xml` file, which will be available to all maven projects.

See the informations here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html